# Where is the place to prove that an answer is not correct?

Tags: support

Someone gave an answer, but it is not correct.

I'd like to give a proof, but the proof takes place and formatting,  and this is clearly too much for a comment.

So: Is there a place here at stackoverflow for such a kind of "article", or do I need to put it on an external website and just post a link?

Comment: Why not simply post an answer of your own? And mention (in short) that the other answer is wrong?

Comment: Put it somewhere and link to it in a comment unless you have the correct answer then you can post it with your answer. You also always have the option to walk away if you are unsure

Comment: If there's not already a correct answer on that question, then just put a correct answer, then comment on the other explaining that there's a problem with theirs and yours is the correct way to do it. (Make sure the comment is polite, of course.)

Comment: The OP hasn't said that he has the correct answer. Just that the given answer is incorrect

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName Mods will decline that flag. Flags should not be used to indicate a wrong answer. That is what voting is for.

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName no, that is incorrect; NAA flags are for indicating posts that don't even *attempt* to answer the question, not posts that try but fail.

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName use **no** flag. There is nothing to flag. The options for an incorrect answer are downvote, comment, give your own answer, walk away. These options can be combined as you wish but there is no flag for an incorrect answer. Mods should not be concerned with technical details (most often, if at all) when reviewing flags. These are things the community can handle ourselves.

Comment: What is wrong with down voting? Its tooltip states *This answer is not useful* which is true for a wrong answer. And suppose there is a new flag, who is going decide that the flag is correct? Do we get a new queue for that?

Comment: Down votes is the simple and right approach for this. Comments can help if you can make them terse enough to make your point. In this situation that seems tough if it would take a lot of code. Code in comments sucks

Comment: @Matt I never downvote.

Comment: @SQLPolice Well that's just wrong. You should downvote if you think an answer is wrong or not useful, that is what it is there for. This helps the good answers get to the top and the bad answers languish at the bottom. THe system works if you use it correctly

Comment: >"Down votes is the simple and right approach" -- This is generally true for subjective statements like "This answer is not useful", but it does not guarantee the correct outcome for objective statements like "This answer is correct."  An answer which is provably but subtly incorrect may already have too many upvotes for one downvote (or a dozen) to impact its reception on the site.  A [wrong answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocentrism) which stands simply because more people believe it than not is still wrong.

Comment: @TinyGiant Stackoverflow became totally abused by the downvotes. Therefore, I never downvote. I am opting for kicking downvotes at all, or making them transparent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I'd like to give a proof, but the proof takes place and formatting, and this is clearly too much for a comment.

This **instantly** rules comments out.  They're meant for temporal, quick communication *anyway*.

> Is there a place here at stackoverflow for such a kind of "article", or do I need to put it on an external website and just post a link?

The best idea is to **post your own answer.**  In doing so, not only do you expose knowledge of the incorrectness of another solution, but you also increase the likelihood that more people will benefit from it.  I mean you no offense, but the chances of someone reading your blog post as opposed to here - *especially* if you just link it here - are vanishingly slim.

In your answering, don't call out the person by name or say that they're wrong or stupid; if you have to attack anything, attack the approach, rationalize why it's not suitable, and offer a more suitable solution of your own.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own answer and keep in mind that the OP is much less interested in comparing one answer to the other than simply getting a good answer. So do not start with a comparison, but simply answer the question. Should your answer be so much better, it may happen that the other answerer deletes his answer.  Then, your answer would look bad and be unusable for future readers, if it only concentrates on the drawbacks of other answers. You certainly should mention your concern, but give it much less prominence.  Maybe you can put it into some general observations that this-or-that cannot work with a closing reference to the other answer.

Comment: Again, the OP has not once said he has an answer. We are only asked what to do with an incorrect answer. Just because the OP knows an answer isn't correct doesn't mean he has the right one. I know that I can't jump off of a building and turn into a frog but I don't know *why* that is

Comment: @codeMagic: I fail to understand your example: What would be the question for the answer "jump off of a building and turn into a frog"?

Comment: @codeMagic Exactly! But I have the *jump-and-frog-proof* ready ;) I possiby would also have an answer, but in that case I would like to show that another answer, which looks good at a 1st look,  can bear problems in some cases. And this leads to some other generic problems. In fact, what I'm looking for is the possibiltiy to write "articles". However, at SO, it seems you can only post "questions" and "answers", no "articles".

Comment: **Q:** "How can I jump off of a building and turn into a frog?" **A:** "You can jump off of a building and turn into a frog by clapping 3 times as you fall and screaming, 'I want to be a frog'". I know that answer is incorrect but I don't know how to properly do it.

Comment: @SQLPolice if you do have an answer then this answer should work for you. And, no, SO does not have a place for articles because that's not what it is for. You can answer then link to an awesome blog post you are going to write. That's perfectly fine as long as it is related and you have answered the question in your post.

Comment: @SQLPolice: exactly such "articles" can easily create a very non-constructive atmosphere full of bile - as you have them in many scientific venues.