# Where to prove an answer does not answer the question, without having an answer

Tags: discussion

Lets say you post a question. Someone gives an answer that *looks* like an answer to the untrained eye, but you know and can prove it isn't. As an OP, you would like to explain why the given answer does not actually answer your question. The comment section does not provide enough space and the adequate formatting to do this.

[This overflow question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298241/where-is-the-place-to-prove-that-an-answer-is-not-correct) asks the same question but assumes you actually have an answer to the OP's question. In this case, I **am** the OP and do not have an answer. Using an answer to illustrate why another answer does not answer the question feels wrong.

Normally, the voting system will sort this out. However not everyone is going to take the time to completely absorb, understand and practice with the material before voting. Adding a proof of why an answer does not answer the question is the only way I see to make people aware of it.

Comment: You could write it up in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) and then write a comment linking to it.

Comment: I'm wary of the statement that you can't explain why an answer is wrong in a comment.  You don't need a rigorous publication worthy proof, just a simple explanation of what it fails to accomplish.

Comment: Ironically @NathanOliver, that's along the lines of what I suggest in that post.  Sure, a Gist isn't quite the same as an *answer*, but an answer is better in that it'll be longer lived.  Funnily enough I was coming by to provide the same advice.

Comment: @Makoto Well.. great minds.. :)

Comment: @Makoto Not that you need to be the OP to downvote...(although not having 125 rep is a bit of a roadblock)

Comment: Create a question about the flaws in the answer and then self-answer with a proof?  That...  actually seems like a bit much, unless the original answer represents a major and common enough problem to have value as an independent Q&A pair.  Or perhaps you've found a way to put the 3000 character limit of a bounty's text to good use.

Comment: @NathanOliver yeah I took that approach but in the 8th comment under "show more comments", the visibility of it is limited.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As the OP, I see two options available to you (and these aren't mutually exclusive):

- Leave a comment on the answer explaining why this isn't a suitable solution for you.  You don't *have* to prove it, but if you can elaborate in a few short sentences, that should be fine.
- Update your question to explain why certain solutions wouldn't be ideal for you or your case.  Again, there's no real need for code; a few sentences should do it.  The more detail you leave in your question, the clearer the guidance to future answerers.

Comment: I like the editing it into the Q.  Same way to argue a dupe isn't a dupe.

Comment: I took both approaches but apparently that [still wasn't enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44526559/how-to-limit-value-type-code-duplication).

Comment: I think the options this answer presents are the best ones we have right now. For most cases, showing why an answer does not answer the question can be done in a comment along with the voting system. For some cases it would be nice if it was possible to provide a single longer reaction per answer, explaining why the answer does not answer the  question. It is reasonable for stackoverflow to not overcomplicate the website for those cases.

Comment: @Mick I think "_It is reasonable for stackoverflow to not overcomplicate the website for those cases_" nails it. I haven't gone through your question and the answer in depth, but for _most cases_, adding detail to a question as to why a proposed solution doesn't work [for you], or why you're still looking for an alternative usually works well. Cases where it doesn't are probably to few and far between to be worth adding more complexity.

Comment: In my experience, leaving a short comment under the answer provokes arguing from the answerer about why their answer is the correct one.  Answerers generally assume that they know more than questioners.  I prefer your second suggestion of editing the question.