# How to deal with answers that, while technically correct, don't answer the question?

Tags: discussion, answers

While reviewing I recently came across two answers that were technically correct in themselves but didn't really answer their questions. To avoid the Meta Effect, I'm not linking them here, but I can if it should be necessary.

- The first question was how a few batch commands could be executed in C#, but the posted answer showed an example using PowerShell instead.
- The second question asked how to avoid `if (someVar == null)` to prevent Null Reference Exceptions and the answer was to use `if (null == someVar)`.

Since in some sense they at least *tried* to answer, I flagged them as Very Low Quality. Both flags were declined, in case of the first

> a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

was given as the reason, for the second question the reason given was

> Code only answers are downvote worthy, not flag worthy. Please note that flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

What would have been the right course of action in those cases?

Comment: Worth noting that on popular questions I occasionally see answers which, while they don't technically answer the question the OP asked, _do_ answer the question all the people reaching the question from Google _really_ came for. These answers often are quite useful IMO, and as a result tend to be highly upvoted (despite not technically answering the OP's question).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If an answer does not answer the question, it is "not useful" as an answer and should be downvoted. You may also leave a comment along the lines "this is a valid suggestion but as an answer it works for some other question", but beware of revenge downvotes.

Flagging as NAA is definitely wrong (as it tries to answer), flagging VLQ may be ok or get declined as you've seen (VLQ is more about link-only/half line of text).

Comment: ["Why and how are some answers deleted? Answers that **do not fundamentally answer the question** may be removed. This includes answers that are: \[...\] not even a partial answer to the actual question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: This is wrong, see @Braiam response, you guys endlessly run around in circles with this question (what to do when some one one answers something that isn't the question), the correct answer is the custom flag this, because this moderator doesn't see/doesn't have enough time to actually see the context of the question, and needs to know it violates not fundamentally answering the question despite the fact it is *an* answer. The fact that it was declined doesn't mean that moderator isn't wrong, it indicates that it is impractical to verify it wasn't an answer to the question on the flag alone

Comment: @Braiam Yes, those answers **may** be removed _via delete votes from 20k+ users_. This answer is absolutely correct that they should not be flagged and should instead be downvoted. Yeah a note about delete votes would be nice, but it is unnecessary as I'm sure anyone who had delete votes would cast them in such a case.

Comment: Which moves us to the next point: 20k users aren't omnipresent. They need the community to bring these issues to them. The 10ker flag queue was supposed to do exactly that, just that it was used for something else since it appeared at 10k instead of 20k.

Comment: @Braiaim as I have said countless times before, trying to fix the system by encouraging it's misuses _does not actually work_. I know that is hard to believe, but it just doesn't. If you want to change the system, make a suggestion and let the community vote on it. Spreading patently false advice is only ever going to make the situation worse, not better.

Comment: @TinyGiant In this circumstance, the answers OP are referring to might actually be answers to the question, but no in general, we should not be relying on 20k users to randomly happen uppon these answers.  We aren't talking about if the user actually answers the question, but is wrong, we are talking about if the user *doesn't actually address the question*.

Comment: @snb I am aware that is what we're talking about, and that does  not change any of my arguments. These answers should not ever be flagged. They should be downvoted, and voted for deletion if applicable.

Comment: @TinyGiant Well apparently others disagree with your assertion that they shouldn't, CodyGray says "***For example, if I was reviewing a NAA flag on a PowerShell answer to a batch question, there's a fairly good chance I would delete it, on the grounds that the answer isn't even in the same ballpark as the question.***"   So no, I don't think you are correct that we shouldn't be flagging these types of answers, or that it is against the rules. I think *not flagging* or encouraging others to not flag these answers hurts the site.

Comment: This problem of A language resulting in B effective outcome will always persist until the NAA flag dialogue is updated from "does not attempt to answer **the question**" to something else. Because some people think it means NAA is valid for answers that don't answer *the question asked by OP*, while the community has decided it is valid only for answers *that aren't an answer to any possible question*, which are two **very different things**.

Comment: @snb Cody didn't say that they should be flagged. He said that if one _was_ flagged _and he reviewed the flag_, then he _might_ delete it even though it shouldn't have been flagged. See [A minor change to the description of the “not an answer” flag: “the question” → “a question”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag-the-question-%E2%86%92) for more discussion on the topic. There are countless posts to reference that all support not flagging these posts.

Comment: One: (as cody mentions) moderators are not expected to be subject matter experts, so should not be expected to determine whether an answer is a applicable to the question asked. Two: NaA flags are reviewed out of context. Unless a moderator explicitly chooses to view the question, all they see is the answer. Three: Flags are just not the right way to deal with these answers. Downvotes and delete votes are a much better means of dealing with them because 1) a post must get below a given score to be delete voted, and delete votes require more trust from the community to obtain than flags.

Comment: Ultimately the point is that these answers _are_ answers, and technically correct, so it _should_ require more skin in the game to delete than posts that are not actually answers and should be cleaned up as fast as humanly possible. Answers that "don't answer **the** question asked" are not _actively harmful_ and as such do not need to be deleted as soon as humanly possible.

Comment: @TinyGiant  And there are countless references supporting flagging these questions even in your link, heck the [accepted answer is a critique of the conclusion that they shouldn't be flagged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286270/2036035).  Additionally Cody never said that "if it doesn't answer the question it shouldn't be flagged" at best he said that if you want to be on the safe side, you have the option of not handling flagging these edge cases... This debate comes up again and again and again, its never been resolved as you state.

Comment: @snb uhhh that's not a critique, that's an example. See also [Your answer is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/288751) or even [When to flag an answer as not an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/4639281). It has been resolved many times, and the fact that you disagree with the community does not make you right. The community has decided that what you're recommending is the incorrect course of action, you refuse to see that but that is a choice that you made.

Comment: [How to mark an answer as “It doesn't answer the question that was asked?”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/4639281), [Where to prove an answer does not answer the question, without having an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350766/4639281), etc, etc. You have yet to provide a reference stating that these posts should in fact be flagged, and I've provided five.

Comment: That is a critique, even if you choose not to look at it that way, it displays the absurdity of leaving these piles of trash everywhere, and "your answer is in another castle" debates link only answers, and even then, there is massive contention in that thread (look at the top rated post...), and your "when to flag an answer as not an answer" supports my point, if it doesn't attempt to answer the question *you can flag it!*

Comment: @snb Wow, you can twist anything to support your point. That is truly an amazing skill. It doesn't make you any less wrong though. It is clear at this point that you have no interest in listening to reason, so I'm going to cease trying to reason with you.

Comment: @TinyGiant I'm sorry I have a different point of view than you? No need to use personal attacks here.  Just because I don't share your opinion doesn't mean I'm trying to "twist anything to support my point"

Comment: @snb Well obviously once you've started twisting everything to mean the opposite of what it actually means, the discussion has reached an end.

Answer (score 16):

Opinions vary on this, and it gets complicated because both regular community members and diamond moderators can (and do) process low quality flags (NAA and VLQ).

The way it's *supposed* to work is that regular members of the community evaluate posts flagged for either of these reasons in the Low Quality Posts (LQP) review queue. However, if they don't handle them fast enough and/or there are too many for the community to handle (because there aren't enough reviewers actively reviewing), then they show up on the moderator dashboard, and we will process them.

Community members looking at flags in the LQP review queue can evaluate the flagged posts as they see fit, and have a bit more leeway than moderators do. For example, while moderators are not supposed to assess the technical veracity of an answer (because moderators are not and cannot be expected to be experts in all technologies that are on-topic for Stack Overflow), expert community members who are reviewing are *encouraged* to do so. This is why we give users with moderator privileges delete votes, and why three delete votes from such users will remove an answer that they deem to be useless.

Naturally, though, when the post goes through a review queue that is open to a large section of our user base, opinions will vary on how the post should be handled.

Even among diamond moderators, there are some minor variations in how such flags are interpreted and processed.

For example, if I was reviewing a NAA flag on a PowerShell answer to a batch question, there's a fairly good chance I would delete it, on the grounds that the answer isn't even in the same ballpark as the question. I see this as distinct from assessing technical merit (which I do not do as a moderator); it is plainly obvious to any observer that the answer is not an answer because it is answering an entirely different question. (There are exceptions to this. If the answer says, "You cannot do this in a batch file, but there is a solution in PowerShell" or "Using PowerShell would be better because…", then that would obviously be an answer and it should not be deleted. You can tell this by reading the answer in context of the question. Again, opinions differ on whether NAA flags should be processed in that manner, or whether the answer should be considered independently to see if it just looks/reads like an answer to a hypothetical question.)

Obviously the moderator who processed your flag doesn't feel the same way I do. Or maybe it wasn't quite as clear cut as you make it out to be. Or maybe the moderator just didn't look carefully enough at the question. You might be able to head this problem off by raising a custom flag and providing more explanation. Don't rely on "not an answer" to be enough of a clue that the answer is regarding an entirely different language than the question; tell them that explicitly.

There are, of course, [general guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) for interpreting and using NAA and VLQ flags, but that doesn't eliminate the reality of varied opinions and judgment calls. Nor should it, in my opinion. There's a reason we have humans review posts: we want them to use their brains.

If you want to always be on the safe side with flags, then you won't be able to flag "edge cases", and you'll need to stick strictly with obvious cases that fit neatly into the established and universally agreed-upon buckets. If, on the other hand, you're more interested in quality and don't mind a few declined flags here and there due to differences of opinion, then feel free to flag anything that you think is actively harmful to the site and needs to be deleted.

---

Looking at your examples in a bit more detail…

In the first case, although you sensibly avoided linking to the exact answer, it is very likely the case that the answer was attempting to recommend PowerShell as a *preferable* alternative to invoking batch commands from C#, and that would (as stated above) constitute a valid answer. In fact, in my technical opinion, it would even constitute a *correct* answer (even though, again, that's not supposed to be a relevant criterion).

In the second case, the answer to use a Yoda condition was just a regular old *wrong* answer, and those are supposed to be downvoted, rather than flagged. Perhaps the answerer misunderstood the question, and you could alleviate that confusion (perhaps even prompting them to delete their own answer and earn a Peer Pressure badge) by leaving a comment to that end. If you have sufficient privileges, feel free to cast a delete vote on useless answers (but you don't have these privileges—not yet). You almost certainly should not flag it, though, as >95% of scenarios will end in such a flag being declined.

In the case of a "code-only" answer, to which you allude, these should ***not*** be flagged. Now, I very much sympathize with the urge to flag them as "very low quality", because I *also* consider code-only answers to be "very low quality". However, you have to think about what flags actually do. See [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355579/how-to-handle-answers-that-are-just-code/355625#355625) for a more detailed explanation of why flags aren't suitable in such cases.

Comment: Some people are taking your answer to mean that these answers should in-fact be flagged. That isn't what I get from your answer, but that may need some clarifying.

Comment: @Tiny Thanks for the heads-up, I guess. That was why I added the last section. Should I...make the answer longer?

Comment: Looking at the comments above, I see the context for the confusion. I actually would be fine with a flag on the first answer if it's really as irrelevant as is implied here. I *do not agree* with changing the wording of the flag from "the question" to "a question". I think that's nonsense. But I will tell you that I am not the only moderator who processes flags, so if you care about having a flag declined and might be upset if that happens, I recommend *not* flagging these, because other moderators might decline them. (Dunno for sure, haven't taken a poll.)

Answer (score -3):

This discussion reappears over time. If answer **attempts to answer the question** it's a valid answer, even if it fails at it's goal. There is a **downvote button** to mark answer as *not useful*, if you find it such.

However, many times answers that touch the bigger picture or add technical details have been very useful to me. The question asked was the top Google result in my search. However, my question was slightly different. If it wasn't for the other answer, I'd be lost.

The question you should ask yourself is whether it's more important to pedantically delete any comment/answer that isn't 100% related to question, or if you want Stack Overflow to be good resource for programmers.

Answer (score -15):

This open ended question invites discussion and opinion. I'll offer mine.

Answering your last question first (What would have been the right course of action...), I would like to see a moderator give us a definitive answer. They can explain why or why they don't agree with the opinions expressed here and tell us what their expectation is.

As for the question in your title (How to deal with answers...), I agree with Alexei that a down vote is appropriate, *if you feel that a vote is necessary*. If the comment is valid and not worthy of a down vote, may I suggest a neutral vote by way of no vote at all? This would neither increase nor decrease the reputation of the poster. Nothing says you have to vote up or down.

Now the real art of handling an improper answer is in creating an entertaining comment to follow it. You don't want to come across as a jerk who says, "You dumba$$, that doesn't remotely provide any help!" The other readers of the thread will not appreciate a crude or sarcastic comment.

If you can provide a better answer, by all means do so! If you don't know the answer, but want to try to help clarify the direction of the thread, I suggest using humor for two reasons.

1. It will entertain the readers and make the forum a more enjoyable
   place.
2. You can make your point without being insulting.

Both of these will help preserve and enhance your own reputation.

That's my opinion. I enjoy your discussion.

Comment: You may want to check out https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308441/using-naa-on-jokes-that-make-no-attempt-to-answer-the-question before proposing something that really against SO policy... Also you may be mixing "comment" and "answer" which are two very different concepts on SO - some [edit] to clarify meaning of "If the comment is valid and not worthy of a down vote" would help (you can't downvote comments on SO).

Comment: Side note: also check out https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328379/why-are-fellow-users-removing-thank-yous-from-my-questions to review guidance on "thank you" text in the posts.

Comment: We don't really need a diamond moderator to give a definitive answer to this: Very Low Quality flags are handled by community members with sufficient rep (I can't recall the number required for VLQ tags) not just diamond mods and we do have a [consensus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue) on when to use this flag.