# Review on a First Post answer to a question wrongly tagged

Tags: discussion

I was looking through the review queues and came across a first answer by someone. It looked wrong - and is a new answer to a [protected question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45883655/is-it-always-safe-to-modify-the-kwargs-dictionary) - and from what I can tell, (1) the *current* question does **not** contain a [Swift] tag which the review does:

[image]

It has *nothing* (question or answer) to do with Swift. While I personally believe this to be an audit on me (and I chose the only option I think I should do and "Skip" it), what exactly *is* the correct thing on something legit? Skip that answer? Remove [Swift] from the question and then... skip? Or comment? Or not care because it was an audit?

Comment: Are you asking how to properly respond to given audit (probably downvote) or how to deal with answer that does not answer the question (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355799/how-to-deal-with-answers-that-while-technical-correct-dont-answer-the-questio) or what exactly?

Comment: That answer [was recently an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17171116), but I have no idea why the question appeared to have a [[tag:swift]] tag. That should not have been part of the audit, and must have been a bug. (The question itself was [also recently an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17161796), but then it would not have appeared greyed-out as in your screenshot. Even then, though, it shouldn't have had irrelevant tags added to it.)